# Clone git project from cloud source repository using Python

Tags: python-3.x, git, google-source-repositories

I would like to clone git project stored on cloud source repository from Python code.
I am using git.Repo.clone_from method and it is working. However, only after I authenticate using procedure described here:
https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/authentication
in "Authenticate by using manually generated credentials" section.

This procedure creates .gitcookies file and setup git to use it with my repository. When I use git.Repo.clone_from method, the same cookie is used as this method probably internally runs git command, which also uses .gitcookies file.
I would like to be independent from local git configuration and pass some login/password or token directly in my application to git.Repo.clone_from method. Is it possible? I even tried to get the cookie from .gitcookies and pass it to git.Repo.clone_from method using env parameter and set there GIT_ASKPASS variable. Unfortunately without success as I do not know what exactly should be set in it.

Comment: This is hardly a git question.

Comment: `git clone` does not use `.gitcookies` by default, but whatever Python library you are using might. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48603575/1256452) for details. You will want a different credential helper; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50081832/1256452).

Comment: You are right, the procedure which I mentioned creates not only .gitcookies file, but also sets it as cookiefile in .gitconfig. The response in question you have mentioned in fact suggests doing the same if I understood properly. I would like to know if the same can be achieved without making changes to .gitconfig, but by passing this cookie to https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.clone_from method.